# Druid: Cached lookup fails because of "Null or Empty Dimension found" during ingestion time

Tags: druid

I am setting up a new kafka ingestion stream into druid. This works fine, but now I need to do a lookup during the ingestion time. I am running apache-druid-0.13.0-incubating.

I have created a Registered Lookup function which finds a optional `referral_id` by a `promo_id`. When I do a lookup introspection for this function it works fine.

Now I want to store the result of this lookup (`referral_id`) in my datasource. The lookup *cannot* be done during query time.

In my dimensionsSpec I have defined the dimension as listed below.

```
{
    "type" : "extraction",
    "dimension" : "promo_id",
    "outputName":"referral_id",
    "outputType": "long",
    "replaceMissingValueWith":"0",
    "extractionFn": {
        "type": "registeredLookup",    
        "lookup": "referral_promoter"
     }
}
```

It does not work. I see this error in the logs:

> WARN [KafkaSupervisor-TEST6] org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.DimensionSchema - Null or Empty Dimension found
>   "2019-01-22T10:08:39,784 ERROR [KafkaSupervisor-TEST6] org.apache.druid.indexing.kafka.supervisor.KafkaSupervisor - KafkaSupervisor[TEST6] failed to handle notice: {class=org.apache.druid.indexing.kafka.supervisor.KafkaSupervisor, exceptionType=class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, exceptionMessage=Instantiation of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.DimensionsSpec] value failed: null (through reference chain: org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.StringInputRowParser["parseSpec"]->org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.JSONParseSpec["dimensionsSpec"]), noticeClass=RunNotice}
>   " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Instantiation of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.DimensionsSpec] value failed: null (through reference chain: org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.StringInputRowParser["parseSpec"]->org.apache.druid.data.input.impl.JSONParseSpec["dimensionsSpec"])
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I have no clue how to solve this. What am I doing wrong? I have tried various dimension configurations, but none worked.

Comment: check your dataset

Comment: I have solved this by passing the data already in the kafka stream so that I do not have to do a lookup at ingestion time.